# Кодировка из ansi в utf8 в парсере новостей

Tags: кодировка, delphi-7, парсер

Взял исходник и переделал под новости, но после этого вместо русских букв начали отображаться иероглифы, мне посоветовали поменять кодировку  из ansi в utf8, но я не знаю как. Вот проект: [Проект.](http://webfile.ru/6300463)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вобще есть стандартная функция **AnsiToUTF8** и обратная ей **utf8ToAnsi**

в вашем проекте нужно заменить всего 1 строку

было

```
...
    ProgressBar1.Position:=ProgressBar1.Position+1;
    Label1.Caption:=q;
    ProgressBar1.Position:=ProgressBar1.Position+1;
...
```

станет

```
ProgressBar1.Position:=ProgressBar1.Position+1;
Label1.Caption:=AnsiToUTF8(q);
ProgressBar1.Position:=ProgressBar1.Position+1;
```